# SQLAlchemy Query API and calculated fields

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

Let's say I want to do a query like this on an SQLite3 database:

```py
SELECT (2 * value) COUNT(2 * value) FROM data GROUP BY (2 * value)
```

A couple of questions:

- Is there a better approach to a query like this?
- How do I create the columns when using the Query API of SqlAlchemy?

Regarding the second point, I can do this:

```py
query = query.add_columns(2 * data.value)
query = query.add_columns(func.count(2 * data.value))
query = query.group_by(2 * data.value)
```

I'm wondering if there's an easier/better way to define `2 * data.value`. My actual query expression is a bit more complicated than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just create variable

```
double = Data.value * 2
q = session.query(double, func.count(double)).group_by(double)
```

Comment: Well I'll be damned - it actually worked. Now I don't suppose you know how to do this with `.add_columns()`? I couldn't get that way to work.